# textIsSelectable property doesn't work with a Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a normal TextView with the [android:textIsSelectable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_textIsSelectable) property on true. This was working perfectly fine, even while I have the TextView inside of a ListView. But now I decided to use the new [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) as my ActionBar and it doesn't work anymore. I don't get a crash or anything, I only see the screen flickering on Lollipop devices when I longPress the TextView. On pre-Lollypop devices I see nothing happening.

Does anybody else have the same issue and is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 4):

If you app theme extends one of `.NoActionBar` themes, you need to enable windowActionModeOverlay, to fix this issue.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This was the fix for me! I extend an AppCompat action bar theme, but I have windowActionBar set to false. Putting this windowActionModeOverlay property back in now has the copy paste controls staying on the screen rather than flashing for a split second. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `layout.xml` file: Replace `fill_parent` with `wrap_content`for this element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me :

In your toolbar layout, add the textview by yourself, an example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text = "Hi, there"
               android:textColor="#ff0000"
               android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I tested this on android v4.0.4 ICS, its working fine for me, I am able to select text on long press.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Why should he include a TextView in his Toolbar layout? He wants to have a contextual menu (copy/paste/select all) when he long presses on a text within the main content